# jQuery or JavaScript for dynamic fields to change the property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to preface this question with the fact that I am not good with jQuery or JavaScript.  I struggled with it in school and after.  I am looking for a little help with getting what to use from the html output.

I am working from ASP.NET MVC Core, and it is generating output as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
     <input name="CraftListA[0].CraftLevelSet" id="CraftListA_0__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">
</div>
```

The MVC View is written as such:

```
//Prior divs and container information for the page

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.CraftListA.Count; i++)
{

 //Identification fields
      <div class="col-md-1">
           <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.CraftListA[i].CraftLevelSet" />                                
      </div>
      //More Loop Code
}
```

The model that the view is working from is as such:

```
 [ComplexType]
    public class CharacterCraftCraftListViewModel
    {
        //Ids for the class
        public bool CraftLevelSet { get; set; }
        public string CraftLevelName { get; set; }
        //More class info
    }
```

What I am looking to do is use jQuery or JavaScript to disable checkboxes automatically.  So if CraftListA[0].CraftLevelSet is unchecked, I want to disable the checkboxes for CraftListA[1].CraftLevelSet through the end of the list.  I know that I would be using the .prop('disabled') or .prop('enabled') to switch the checkbox.  I believe that I would also be using the .prop('checked') to make the verification.  I am thinking along the lines of:

```
$(function () {
   $("#chkBoxDisabled").change(){
       (this).prop('disabled');
   });
});
$(function () {
   $("#chkBoxEnabled").change(){
       (this).prop('enabled');
   });
});
$(function () {
   if $("name^=['CraftListA[0]__CraftLevelSet']").("#chkBoxEnabled")
   else if $("name^=['CraftListA{0}__CraftLevelSet']" - 1).prop('checked') == 'Checked'
      (this).("#chkBoxEnabled")
   else (this).("#chkBoxDisabled");
});
```

Clearly though this did not work.  I have an idea where it goes wrong, and that is grabbing the html name or id.  Though I am also not sure about the rest of the code.  I was able to get some of the above code by looking over about a 100 websites.  I am also working by myself and have no one to bounce ideas off of, so that is why I am turning here.  Any help that anyone can give, or even a direction of where to turn would be helpful.  I have run the above through JSFiddle before and as I expected, it didn't work there either.

**UPDATE:**
After much playing I have come down to a solution that works.  But I am stumped on how to use it with another checkbox class.  If class 1 is not checked, everything after in class 1 should not be checked, and class 2 should not be checked.  If it is checked then it opens up the next checkbox in the class, plus the first available checkbox in class 2.

Here is what I have going, and each class alone works.  How do I get them to work together?

```js
//The below code works, but it might be limiting for the scope.
var fieldsA = $(".cALScb");
fieldsA.change(function () {
    Array.prototype.reduce.call(fieldsA, function (prev, curr) {
        curr.disabled = !prev.checked || prev.disabled;
    
        //This didn't work
        //var $child = $(this).closest("td").find(".cALMcb").eq(1);

        //If you want to uncheck remaining use this instead of above line:
        curr.checked = prev.checked ? curr.checked : false;
        curr.disabled = !prev.checked;

        return curr;
        //$child.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
});

fieldsA.change();

//The below code works, but it might be limiting for the scope.
var fieldsAM = $(".cALMcb");
fieldsAM.change(function () {
    Array.prototype.reduce.call(fieldsAM, function (prev, curr) {
        curr.disabled = !prev.checked || prev.disabled;


        //If you want to uncheck remaining use this instead of above line:
        curr.checked = prev.checked ? curr.checked : false;
        curr.disabled = !prev.checked;

        return curr;
    });
});

fieldsAM.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[0].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_0__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Apprentice</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[0].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_0__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[1].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_1__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Journeyman</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[1].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_1__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[2].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_2__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Expert</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[2].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_2__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[3].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_3__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Artisan</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[3].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_3__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[4].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_4__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Master</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[4].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_4__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[5].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_5__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">                  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Supreme</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[5].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_5__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[6].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_6__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">           
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Westfold</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[6].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_6__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[7].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_7__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Eastenmnet</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[7].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_7__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[8].CraftLevelSet" class="cALScb" id="CraftListA_8__CraftLevelSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelSet field is required." data-val="true">                 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <b>Westemnet</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input name="CraftListA[8].CraftLevelMastery" class="cALMcb" id="CraftListA_8__CraftLevelMastery" type="checkbox" value="true" data-val-required="The CraftLevelMastery field is required." data-val="true">
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
```

If we look at my javascript we can see I tried to use the following two lines, but they did nothing, essentially.

```
var $child = $(this).closest("td").find(".cALMcb").eq(1);
$child.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
```

It is quite possible I have the format wrong or maybe I am trying to wrong thing.  Any help would be nice.

Comment: What happens  if `CraftListA[2].CraftLevelSet` is unchecked ? You want to disable all checkboxes from `CraftListA[3].CraftLevelSet` to n ?

Comment: The real question is why you would want to do this. Unchecked boxes do not post a value so if some of `CraftLevelSet` properties are `true`, they will be bound to `false` in the POST method.

Comment: And if you did want to do it, your give the checkboxes a class name and use that to select and loop through the checkboxes.

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkqc8obL/) for an example

Comment: @Shyju to answer your question yes, if CraftListA[2].CraftLevelSet is unchecked I would want to disable CraftListA[3].CraftLevelSet to n, but if it is checked, then enabled CraftListA[3].CraftLevelSet, move to CraftListA[4].CraftLevelSet and see if CraftListA[3].CraftLevelSet is checked.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the reason behind this is a form of gating.  To ensure that a requirement is met before allowing a checkbox from being used.  I am looking at the fiddle and it looks close to what I am looking at, if the first is unchecked, they are all disabled.  I am sure there is a way to step through it.